# Playing Billiards

Tags: code-golf, geometry, optimization, path-finding

In this code golf, you will have to determine the direction of the shortest shot that hits exactly **n** cushions before falling into a pocket.

The billiard table is a 6 pocket pool table with the following characteristics:

- Dimensions are variable (**a** x **b**)
- No friction : the ball will roll forever until it falls into a pocket
- Pockets and ball sizes are almost zero. This means that the ball will fall in the pocket only if they have same position.
- The ball is placed at the bottom left hole at the beginning (but doesn't fall in it)

[image: 3cushion]

Create a full program or function that takes the dimensions (**a**,**b**) of the table and a the number of cushions to hit **n** as input and returns the angle in degrees of the shortest path hitting exactly **n** cushions before falling into a pocket.

- ***a*** > 0
- ***b*** > 0
- 0 <= ***n*** < 10000000
- 0 < ***alpha*** < 90 (in degrees) precision : at least 10^-6

### examples :

with **a** = 2, **b** = 1, **n** = 1
there are three possible paths : (1) (2) (3) on the following figure.
the number (1) is the shortest so the output should be atan(2) = 63.43494882292201 degrees

[image: 1cushion]

The solution for **a** = 2, **b** = 1, **n** = 4 is atan(4/3) = 53.13010235415598 degrees

[image: 4cushions]

### test samples :

```
a = 2,    b = 1,    n = 1,       -> alpha = 63.43494882292201
a = 2,    b = 1,    n = 2,       -> alpha = 71.56505117707799
a = 2,    b = 1,    n = 3,       -> alpha = 75.96375653207353
a = 2,    b = 1,    n = 4,       -> alpha = 53.13010235415598
a = 2,    b = 1,    n = 5,       -> alpha = 59.03624346792648
a = 2,    b = 1,    n = 6,       -> alpha = 81.86989764584403
a = 4.76, b = 3.64, n = 27,      -> alpha = 48.503531644784466
a = 2,    b = 1,    n = 6,       -> alpha = 81.86989764584403
a = 8,    b = 3,    n = 33,      -> alpha = 73.24425107080101
a = 43,   b = 21,   n = 10005,   -> alpha = 63.97789961246943
```

This is code/billiard golf : shortest code wins!

Comment: Does the ball have to hit *exactly* `n` cushions, or *at least* `n` cushions?

Comment: @PeterTaylor exactly n cushions

Comment: isn´t the shortest path always back and forth between the left side top and bottom and then into one of the middle holes?

Comment: no, look at the 2 1 4 example. This path is sqrt(25) = 5 long whereas your solution is sqrt(26)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Python 2.7, <s>352</s> <s>344</s> 281 bytes

```
from math import*
def l(a,b,n):
 a*=1.;b*=1.
 r=set()
 for i in range(1,n+3):
  t=[]
  for k in range(1,i):
   for h in[0,.5]:
    x=(i-k-h)
    if 1-(x/k in r):r.add(x/k);t+=(x*a,k*b),
 d=(a*n+1)**2+(b*n+1)**2
 for x,y in t:
  if x*x+y*y<d:d=x*x+y*y;o=degrees(atan(y/x))
 return o
```

- **-16 bytes** thanks to @Dschoni

Explanation: instead calculating the cushions hits, I'm adding n tables and taking the new holes as valid :
 [image: billard]
Black border/holes is the original, green border/holes is the valid for n=1, red border/holes is the valid for n=2 and so on.
Then I remove the invalid holes (e.g. the blue arrow for n=1). I'll have a list of valid holes and their coordinates, then I calculate their distance from initial point, and then the angle of the smaller distance.

Notes:

<s>a=4.76, b=3.64, n=27 - give 52.66286, trying to figure out why</s> fixed, and saved 8 bytes in the process =D

a=43, b=21, n=10005 - takes ~80 seconds (but gives the right angle)

readable version:

```
from math import *
def bill(a,b,n):
    a=float(a)
    b=float(b)
    ratios = set()
    for i in range(0,n+2): # Create the new boards
        outter = []
        j=i+1
        for k in range(1,j): # Calculate the new holes for each board
            #y=k
            for hole_offset in [0,0.5]:
                x=(j-k-hole_offset)
                if (x/k) not in ratios:
                    ratios.add(x/k)
                    outter.append((x*a,k*b))
    min_dist = (a*n+1)**2+(b*n+1)**2
    for x,y in outter:
        if x*x+y*y<min_dist:
            min_dist = x*x+y*y
            min_alpha=degrees(atan(y/x))
    return min_alpha
```

Comment: You can save a byte by removing the space in  `: degrees`

Comment: I have no idea how your answer works (mathwise) but I think you can gain 1 byte by removing the space after the colon. :) (What @MorganThrapp said)

Comment: This path is valid, but it's not the shortest in all cases, for example with 2 1 4..

Comment: This also assumes that `b < a`. That could easily fixed by getting the minimum/maximum of `a` and `b` though.

Comment: fixed  ( sorta )

Comment: Looks better now! a=4.76, b=3.64, n=27 is designed to test invalid path like your blue one. This path falls in a middle pocket after 13 hits. It might be due to floatting point precision. I would suggest you calculate paths ratios as a couple of integer (y=2*k,x=2*j-2*k-2*hole_offset) and use only a,b to calculate angles and length.

Comment: some hints... instead of explicit type conversion, use the inbuilt implicit when doing multiplication: a=1.0*a (saves 6 byte). the not in line can be made to: if -(x/y in r) , can be definitely golfed further by using lambdas and for loop bracketing etc...

Comment: Probably also shouldn't use b inside b()

Comment: Wow, I found out so much about python by playing with your example, that I had to come back again. list.append((a,b)) can be written as list+=(a,b), (With coma)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>133</s> 117 bytes

This is my implementation:

With a 2x1 table, a path will hit exactly n cushions before going into a pocket if:
(x-1)/2 + (y-1) == n and x,y are mutually primes.
where x,y are the distance of the ball over horizontal/vertical axes.

Paths are the same with arbitrary table size, so we just have to update lengths and angles with (a,b) and keep the shortest.
Path length is sqrt((x*a/2)^2+(y*b)^2) and angle is atan((y*b)/(x*a/2))

```haskell
z=toEnum
f a b n=minimum[[z x^2+r^2,180/pi*atan(r/z x)]|x<-[1..2*n+2],y<-[n+1-div(x-1)2],r<-[2*b/a*z y],gcd x y<2]!!1
```